# Comparison of Metamask vs Ganache

Tags: metamask, ganache, react

I watched some videos about `Metamask` but I am so confused by it

> Metamask: To use the final application like the end user would.

Based on that, what is the purpose of `React` then?

What are the differences between `Ganache` and `Metamask`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those two products are completely different.

**Metamask** is a blockchain wallet (account management) that secures a private key and helps you to interact with an Ethereum Blockchain network (like mainnet, testnet, private networks or local).

It's a Browser extension (Chrome/Firefox/Brave) that triggers a popup when a user tries to send a transaction to the blockchain, in this popup, the user needs to accept the transaction (sign the transaction with the private key).

Your dApp is a web application (React or other), rather than interacting with a traditional HTTP API, it interacts with a blockchain that requires client signature (using private key) to send a transaction.

Metamask manages that part of handling securely your private keys, signing transactions and communicating with the network.

> Metamask is a tool for dApp users.

[Metamask Knowledge Base for more information](https://metamask.helpscoutdocs.com/)

---

**Ganache** is a tool for developers that allows you to run a private and local blockchain on your machine. It's a very useful tool because a blockchain is a complex peer2p distributed system, so it allows developers to deploy and test locally their development (smart contracts) before going to a public network (mainnet or testnet)

> Ganache is a tool for dApp developers.

[Ganache documentation](https://truffleframework.com/ganache)