# Looking for an Ethereum sniffer

Tags: transactions, nodes, blocks

I have been looking for a sniffer similar to Bitcoin P2P Network Sniffer (https://github.com/sebicas/bitcoin-sniffer) which could allow me to connect to Ethereum nodes and listen to blocks and transactions.

Does anybody know such a sniffer?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is software already developed that is able to connect to nodes and detect transactions, however, they do run differently than the bitcoin-sniffer on the link you have provided. Here is a couple of popular suites/frameworks that allow you to do such things, there are also plenty more out there.

1. Ganache, a suite that is designed to run tests, execute commands and inspect states on a blockchain with a built-in explorer that can examine 
   blocks and transactions https://truffleframework.com/ganache
2. Ethstats, a visual interface used to receive stats from running nodes. See https://github.com/cubedro/eth-netstats and https://ethstats.net/

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The sniffer I need should be able to start a connection to other nodes such as geth does. However, Ganache seems to be used only for local, test blockchains (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/55758/42431) and ethstats needs nodes to voluntarily provide their stats (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Network-Status#listing).